# Scraping multiple sub-pages of multiple URLs

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a list of  base URLs as follows :

```
PostURL
www.abc.com/2315Azxc
www.abc.com/1478Bnbx
www.abc.com/6734Gytr
www.abc.com/8912Jqwe
```

Each URL has sub pages like

```
www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=1
www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=2
www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=3
```

I know scraping of data from multiple sub pages of one base URL using `rvest` as follows:

```
df<- lapply(paste0(' www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=', 1:3),
                    function(url){
                      url %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_nodes(".xg_border") %>% 
                        html_text()
                    })
```

But It will require much attention/time to scrape one by one. I am looking for the solution which can scrape data from multiple sub pages of base URLs.

Comment: Every URL `www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=1` and `www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=2` are independent. I don't think there is some shortcut that you can use to scrape the data from two pages without scraping them individually.

Comment: What errors are you getting withe the lapply call?

Comment: I am able to scrap data from www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=1 and www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=2 in a single go. But i want to scrap the data of URLs        www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=1, www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=2, www.abc.com/1478Bnbx&page=1, www.abc.com/1478Bnbx&page=2

Comment: Which code did you use to scrape the two urls in one go? Can you update your post with it?

Comment: i already mentioned the code in my post .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct link to all the URL's using `outer` :

```
all_links <- c(t(outer(df$PostURL, paste0('&page=', 1:3), paste0)))
all_links

# [1] "www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=1" "www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=2" "www.abc.com/2315Azxc&page=3"
# [4] "www.abc.com/1478Bnbx&page=1" "www.abc.com/1478Bnbx&page=2" "www.abc.com/1478Bnbx&page=3"
# [7] "www.abc.com/6734Gytr&page=1" "www.abc.com/6734Gytr&page=2" "www.abc.com/6734Gytr&page=3"
#[10] "www.abc.com/8912Jqwe&page=1" "www.abc.com/8912Jqwe&page=2" "www.abc.com/8912Jqwe&page=3"
```

Now you can use the same `lapply` code to scrape each page.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(PostURL = c("www.abc.com/2315Azxc", "www.abc.com/1478Bnbx", 
"www.abc.com/6734Gytr", "www.abc.com/8912Jqwe")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Its working fine. Suppose the main page "www.abc.com/8912Jqwe" has only two sub page, i.e.  "www.abc.com/8912Jqwe&page=1"  "www.abc.com/8912Jqwe&page=2". With this above code if not founding the third page it doesnt show the error and again goes to first page and return the data from first page only. In the above code, i am looking if any base URl doesnt have three pages it should stop at move to next

Comment: @djMohit You can use `tryCatch` see here an example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701774/how-can-i-web-scraping-without-the-problem-of-null-website-in-r/